# Tkinter Text closes but ipython console keeps running indefinetly

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to print some rows of a pandas dataframe for the user of my tkinter GUI. However, in this test, the tk window is showed, but when closed, the code stop running.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import sys 
from tkinter import * 

dates = pd.date_range('20160101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

root = Tk() 

t1 = Text(root) 
t1.pack() 

class PrintToT1(object): 
 def write(self, s): 
  t1.insert(END, s) 

sys.stdout = PrintToT1() 

print ('Hello, world!') 
print (df)

mainloop() 
root.destroy()

print(2)
```

I am running the script in Spyder, and when I close the window, the ipython console continues processing something, but it never reaches the last line to print the number 2, and I have to restart the console manually.

I want it to close the tk window and continues the script, since in the GUI, after closing the tk window, the code will have to do some calculations for the user. How could I do this?

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it or not, but `mainloop` normally won't return until the root window has already been destroyed. Calling `destroy` after the fact should throw an error. Maybe that error is causing a problem with the ipython console.

Comment: If you execute your script in a console, you will get exceptions.  Try to fix the exceptions one by one: 1) add a dummy `flush()` function in `PrintToT1` class; 2) save the `sys.stdout` before assigning it to `PrintToT1()`; 3) remove `root.destroy()`; 4) restore `sys.stdout` before `print(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKBUX.jpg)

I am new here (page) but the error is that the mainloop is a loop itself If you close the window the program closes.

```
root_window.mainloop()
#destroy()use in ithems or daughters windows
```

test add:
    def date_name(self):

```
    t3 = Toplevel(root)
    t3.geometry('240x100+20+20')
    t3.title("...")
    t3.destroy()#use valid
```

The sample of the data in that window and the function destroy ().

Find how to use the Canvas and the Frame if you want to request the data from the same window but the fields of texts and buttons belong to the cambas ... well I work like that in tkinter.

```
canvas_menu = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
canvas_menu.destroy()#this use valid
```

root.destroy not valid Tk()is a funcion.

test:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
def new_window():
    t3 = Toplevel(root)
    t3.geometry('240x100+20+20')
    t3.title("...")
    Label(t3,text="I hope to help you").pack()
    Button(t3,text="destroy() in t3 ",command=t3.destroy).pack()
canvas_c=Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas_c.pack()
canvas_c.config(bg="blue")
Label(canvas_c,text="info").place(x=100,y=250)

ba=Button(root,text="new_window",command=new_window).pack()
bb=Button(root,text="destroy() in canvas",command=canvas_c.destroy).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and run [run.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC6db.jpg)